# Applying the Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to apply the Chinese remainder theorem to obtain the unique solution modulo $10^n$ for $N\equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$ and $N\equiv 0 \pmod {5^n}$. I have [reason to suppose](http://oeis.org/A007185) that the solution is $5^{2^n}$ but am unable to show it.

The question is motivated by the problem of finding automorphic numbers in base 10 which end with the digit $5$.

I asked a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703830/bezouts-identity-for-prime-powers) today regarding this but the (nice) answer obtained there is not helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show by induction that $5^{(2^n)}\equiv 1\pmod{2^n}$. If $5^{(2^k)}$ is of the shape $q2^k +1$, then, squaring, we find that $5^{(2^{k+1})}=q^2 2^{2k}+q2^{k+1}+1$. Since if $k\ge 1$, we have $2k\ge k+1$. This completes the induction step.